# Jquery tabs with forms in each tab submission to database

Tags: php

Hi? i'm having problems with my jquery tabs in my code every time i try to submit data to the database from one of the tabs, the submit returns me to the first tab.besides that an era at the first tab to since the data is read but doesn't submit in reaching at the mysql_query();section . Please help

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

if(isset($_REQUEST['Question1']) AND !empty($_REQUEST['Question1'])) {
//database insert code
 $question='1';         
 $answer =$_POST['Question1'];

    //header("location:question.php?question=$question&answer=$answer"); 
//$quest = $_GET['question'];
//$ans = $_GET['answer'];
$query = "insert into answered_q(quesNo,answer) values('$question','$answer')";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
var_dump($question,$answer);    
}   
   }

  if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
   if(isset($_REQUEST['Question2']) AND !empty($_REQUEST['Question2'])) {
//database insert code
$question='2';          
$answer =$_POST['Question2'];
$query = "insert into answered_q(quesNo,answer) values('$question','$answer')";
$sql = mysql_query($query);         
var_dump($answer);
 }}
```

the tabs

- Question1
- Question2

```
    <input checked="checked" name="Question1" type="radio" value = "A">Male.</input>
    <input  name="Question1" type="radio" value= "B">Female.</input>
    <p align="center">
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form></p></div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
<p>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post">
    <input checked="checked" name="Question2" type="radio" value = "A">short time span.</input>
    <input  name="Question2" type="radio" value= "B">one year.</input>
    <p align="center">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form></p></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason submitting keeps returning you to the first tab is because when you submit a form, it performs a page-redirect, effectively reloading the page. And when you load the page, it'll automatically choose the first tab as the active one.

The way to get around this is to use some type of AJAX-form plugin, such as [this one](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). It makes the form submission an AJAX call, instead of a page redirect.